# No default construtor exist for class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10fMm.png)

No deafult constructor exist for "DynamicArray" class. Can't figure out why, please help.
[Parts of code(link)](https://pastebin.com/AawcRTzr)

P.S. I did all includes.

```
//----------- list.h
class List {
    DynamicArray _array;
    size_t _size;

public:

    List ();  // allocate items, set capacity and size
    ....
//----------- list.cpp
List::List ()
{
    DynamicArray::DynamicArray _array{I_CAP};
    _size = 0;
}
    ....
//----------- dynamic_array.h
class DynamicArray {
    size_t _capacity;
    std::string *_array;

public:

    DynamicArray (size_t size);
    ....
//----------- dynamic_array.cpp
DynamicArray::DynamicArray (size_t size)
{
    _array = (std::string *)malloc(sizeof(std::string)*size);
    _capacity = size;
}
//----------
```

Comment: Well, you provided a custom constructor for `DynamicArray`, so the default one wasn't generated. Also, please read: [mcve].

Comment: Oh, you are right, really dumb mistake

Comment: I assume you're writing things this way as an exercise, instead of using `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Add default constructor for DynamicArray , DynamicArray::DynamicArray(){} and try.